# Possible application of Rouche's theorem or Hurwitz theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $p(z,w)=\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^mp_{jk}z^jw^k\in\mathbb{C}[z,w]$. Suppose $p(z,w)\neq 0$ for $z, w\in\mathbb{D}$. Then for each $w_0\in\partial\mathbb{D}$ either $w-w_0$ divides $p(z,w)$ or $p(z,w_0)\neq 0$ for $z\in\mathbb{D}$.Here $\mathbb{D}$ is a unit disk.

Can I apply Rouche's theorem or Hurwitz theorem to see this? Actually I have very little idea about this problem. Any idea or help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $q_{w_0}(z)=p(z,w_0)=\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^mp_{jk}z^jw_0^k$ and note that $w-w_0$ divides $p(z,w)-q_{w_0}(z)$ so we need to prove that either $q_{w_0}=0$ or $q_{w_0}(z)$ doesn't vanish inside the unit disc. So wlog assume $q_{w_0}(z)$ is not identically zero, but there is $|z_0|<1, p(z_0,w_0)=0,|w_0|=1$

But now picking $w_n \to w_0, |w_n|<1$ we have that $p(z,w_n) \to p(z,w_0)$ normally (actually uniformly on any large disc since they are polynomials of fixed degree) so by Hurwitz, there are $z_n \to z_0, n \ge N, p(z_n,w_n)=0$ which is a contradiction since $|z_n| <1, n \ge N$ as $|z_0|<1$